# What is ''524 Server Error''?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

[image]

When running my code, sometimes I find this `524 Server Error: Origin Time-out for url` and then my code stop. The error is in `job_monitor`? And how can I solve it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not only unclear, but I also can't see how it relates to quantum computing (in comparison to general programming)

Answer (score 1):

This error code means there was a time-out waiting for a response from the server. It could have been caused by a blip in the network. I would try running the same code again, and seeing if you consistently get this error. If not, then I would not worry, as you are unlikely to see it again.